# is it possible to remove the root output when using @textea/json-viewer

Tags: typescript

I am using @textea/json-viewer to show some json string, but the json always have some root element, for example:

```
import './App.css';
import { JsonViewer } from '@textea/json-viewer';

function App() {

  const json = {
    a: 1
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <JsonViewer value={json}></JsonViewer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when output value is :

```
"root":{
"a":1
}
```

what I really want is like this:

```
{
"a":1
}
```

I have read the [official document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@textea/json-viewer) and did not found any way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop that changes this is `rootName`

```
<div className="App">
  <JsonViewer value={json} rootName={false}></JsonViewer>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

I looked through PRs and issues on the GitHub repo that included the word "root" and found one that mentions this prop name. https://github.com/TexteaInc/json-viewer/pull/57

It's also the second field mentioned on the [official documentation](https://viewer.textea.io/#options), what you linked was just the README.md

[image]